# Groovy-Passing Integer array to PLSQL

Tags: arrays, groovy, plsql, integer

I am calling a Stored Procedure that takes the input as array of numbers.

From the the Groovy side i am passing the int[] to that stored procedure.

But i am getting "Invalid Column Type" as the result from Stored Procedure.

Could somebody suggest me that how to pass a array of numbers from Groovy side?

The TYPE that i have created in Stored Procedure side is; 
create or replace TYPE NUMBER_LIST IS TABLE OF NUMBER;

The int[] in groovy is; 
int[] boxIntArr = new int[5];

Can we pass the boxIntArr in place of NUMBER_LIST?

Answer (score 1):

You should be passing in an instance of [`java.sql.Array`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Array.html) rather than a raw `int[]`.  You can convert the Java array to a SQL array with [`java.sql.Connection.createArrayOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createArrayOf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29).

EDIT:

Oracle doesn't support the standard `Connection.createArrayOf()` method.  Use the Oracle specific [`OracleConnection.createARRAY()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html#createARRAY_java_lang_String__java_lang_Object_) method instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot Taylor.  
When i try to do that;  
java.sql.Array inputJobIdArray = sql.getDataSource().getConnection().createArrayOf("NUMBER_ARRAY", jobIntArr)               

I am getting the error below;caused exception: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.createArrayOf(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/sql/Array;

Note: jobIntArr is a Integer[]

Comment: See edit above.  The Oracle driver has a non-standard method for doing that.